# Подпроект qtcreator: multiple definition of main

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Подключаю к проекту (цель - исполняемый файл) другой проект (тоже исполняемый, то есть не библиотека) как подпроект. Вот фрагмент .pro:

```
include(adscreen/adscreen.pri)
```

(Директория подпроекта в поддиректории adscreen основной директории проекта.)

Содержимое adscreen.pri:

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick
CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += $$PWD/main.cpp

RESOURCES += $$PWD/qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)
```

То есть только добавил `$$PWD` перед именами файла, единственное отличие от предыдущего adscreen.pri

Но ведь функция main должна быть и там и там (я хочу запускать экран с рекламными фильмиками на системе без менеджера окон, то есть типа скринсейвер), неужели только библиотечные подпроекты могут быть подключены?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один проект - один исполнимый файл. Если хочется иметь несколько проектов с несколькими исполнимыми файлами, нужно их объеденить в специальный проект.

Для этого создаете ещё один pro файл, который находиться на уровень выше. И наполняете где то таким содержимым

```
# эта строка нужна, если не хочется заморачиваться 
# и пусть все проекты собираются в порядке упоминания
CONFIG += ordered

# а это то, что это такой себе "суперпроект"
TEMPLATE = subdirs

# список папок с вложенными проектами
SUBDIRS = server client/simple client/second
```

То есть, теперь должна быть такая структура

```
project.pro
server/
   server.pro
   ...файлы проекта
client/
   simple/
     simple.pro
     ...
   second/
     second.pro
     ...
```

Ключевой момент - имя папки и проекта, который в ней лежит, должны совпадать. Если это невозможно (по рядку причин), то можно ручками все прописать. То есть, создается просто имя проекта (виртуальное) и ему прописываются параметры: где лежат исходники, от кого зависит. Детали [в оффициальной документации](https://wiki.qt.io/SUBDIRS_-_handling_dependencies). Пример прямо оттудова

```
template = subdirs

 SUBDIRS = \
           lib2 \   # наши проекты
           lib  \ эти имена - фейковые
           app

 # а теперь расскажем qmake где искать данные по проекту
 lib2.subdir = src/lib2
 lib.subdir  = src/lib
 app.subdir  = src/app

 # А также, укажем зависимости
 # теперь проекты lib lib2 будут собраться "в паралель" (а могут и по очереди, как получиться) и только потом будет собираться app.
 app.depends = lib lib2
```

Этот способ не содержит слова "ordered" и является предпочитаемым. Он также благоприяно сказывается на времени сборки.

Comment: да, похоже что по быстрому проект не перестроить, придется отказаться от идеи строить оба проекта одним кликом до лучших времен :) Спасибо!

Comment: Это переписывается за минут десять. И собираться будет также одной кнопкой. Но если поменялся зависимый проект, а запускаем основной, то пересобирутся оба.

Comment: если локально, то да. Но так как на директорию выше, то еще репозиториум переделывать (пересоздавать) придется. Лучше просто добавлю как подпапку

Comment: На самом деле все можно в одну кучу сбросить или сделать новый проект, а два старых как сабмодули

Comment: в данном случае не думаю, что этот подпроект будет меняться слишком часто, но на будущее учту ваши советы, спасибо еще раз!